# Vue check if "v-model.number" (Modifier) is being used

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

**There is a way to know when it is being used v-model.number?**

```js
<component v-model.number="value" />
```

component.vue

```js
...
onMounted(() => {
  if (props.modelValue.isUsingModifierNumber()){
    console.log('Yes')
  }
})
...
```

Comment: You want to know when `value` is modified ?

Comment: @PierreSaid No, I want to know if the modifier "number" is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vue 3, `v-model` modifiers are passed as a `modelModifiers` prop - see the [docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-custom-events.html#handling-v-model-modifiers)

1. define a prop on your component

```js
props: {
    modelValue: Number,
    modelModifiers: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => ({})
    }
  }
```

2. Test

```js
created() {
  if(this.modelModifiers.number) 
  {
    // ....
  }
}
```